# How sqoop avoid exporting duplicated data from HDFS to RDBMS?

Tags: hdfs, sqoop

HDFS stores data in replication form, when we move data from HDFS to RDBMS by using SQOOP, How sqoop avoid exporting duplicated data from HDFS to RDBMS?

Answer (score 0):

Internally HDFS handles replication. You usually read file using HDFS protocol/ HDFS API then hdfs internally manages this and return only one copy of data.

Sqoop also uses HDFS API/protocol to read data.

So, there no need for extra handling on sqoop end.